# Added a user with adduser, but can't login with that user through FTP

Tags: ftp, vsftpd

I'm setting up and FTP server, and I want to be able to login myself and do whatever I want, but if I want others to connect to my server, I give them credentials that restrict them to the home directory.
I've created the user with:

```
adduser username
passwd username
mkdir /home/user_dir
usermod -d /home/user_dir
```

I then enabled `chroot_local_user=YES` and `chroot_list_enable`, created a file and put my username in it so that I still have access to the entire machine.

If I ftp as myself, I can login and do whatever I want, but I can't login as this new user. (I get `530 Login Incorrect`).

**Info:**

Linux Mint

Using vsftpd

I can login to a shell as the new user (`su newUser... password`)

<s>Also - if I remove myself from the chroot list, I get the `500 OOPS refusing to run with writeable root inside chroot`. I'm assuming this error will be the same with the new user, how do I give them restricted access if I get this error when restricting their access?</s>
Fixed - forgot about writeable chroot

Comment: What FTP server are you using and what's your OS?  Did you try to login to a shell with this user?

Comment: Edited the original post with more info

Comment: Don't just try a simple `su` like that, try to login to a shell to see if the user is blocked by something else.

Comment: I thought that's what `su` did? How do I do a proper login? The user is not there at boot, so something must be missing

Comment: What do you mean that the user is not there at boot?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at your /etc/passwd file
Find your user and look shell (example ttr:x:501:501::/home/username/ttr:/sbin/nologin)
Add this shell (/bin/false or /sbin/nologin) to your /etc/shell or /etc/shells
After that, check your connection

Try again...If it still does not work

Back up the config file before making a change;

```
sudo cp /etc/vsftpd.conf /etc/vsftpd.conf.back
```

and then edit vsftpd.conf (with vi or nano)

```
nano /etc/vsftpd.conf
```

Then make the following change

```
pam_service_name=ftp
```

Save your change and restart the ftp server (if you use nano hit CTRL+O & enter to save then CTRL+X to exit)

```
sudo service vsftpd restart
```

Comment: I built a system to OPs definition, and this was the only thing that worked. I have deleted my answer and upvoted this one instead.

Comment: Thanks!  I initially misread your post and was suggesting you use SFTP, but glad I corrected myself

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/617370/why-vsftpd-doesnt-work-when-pam-service-name-vsftpd/766379#766379 says setting pam_service_name to `ftp` is wrong. You could even set it to `funnystuff` having the same effect.