# Why does vsftp return 530 incorrect login?

Tags: arch-linux, login, ftp, vsftpd

I started a `vsftpd` server on my arch linux desktop and then tried to log in to it using using my normal user. But I get "530 Login incorrect" when I attempt to log in:

```
$ systemctl start vsftpd

$ groups
wheel tom

$ hostname
desktop

$ ftp desktop
Connected to desktop.localdomain.
220 Just to make extra sure the server is configured by this file.
Name (desktop:tom):
331 Please specify the password.
Password:
530 Login incorrect.
ftp: Login failed.
ftp> 221 Goodbye.
```

#### /etc/vsftpd.conf

```
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
ftpd_banner=Just to make extra sure the server is configured by this file.
listen=YES

# I also tried different combinations of these, no dice
# seccomp_sandbox=NO
# pam_service_name=ftp
```

Is there any config change that will fix this and enable me to log in? I can't tell what I'm doing differently from everyone else.

Comment: This question is a duplicate and already answered [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/337799/264715)

Answer (score 1):

/etc/vsftpd.conf:

`pam_service_name=vsftpd`